# How to get value of --config flag during k6 test run

Tags: k6

I want to add a guard clause to my k6 test to ensure a `--config` flag has been set.

How can I read the value of the `--config` flag passed into k6 during a test run?

Comment: I think you should use **k6/execution** module. And to read value of the `--config` flag, there was a function called `execution.configValues()` or something like that

Comment: I don't think you can detect that `--config` itself was specified, you can only read the consolidated options that end up in your script. Why do you need the options to be explicitly set via `--config` and not another mechanism, e.g. environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to detect that specifically `--config` was used to set an option, but it is possible to [read the final, consolidated options from within your scripts](https://grafana.com/docs/k6/latest/using-k6/k6-options/how-to/#get-an-option-value-from-the-script):

> ```
> import exec from 'k6/execution';
>
> export const options = {
>   stages: [
>     { duration: '5s', target: 100 },
>     { duration: '5s', target: 50 },
>   ],
> };
>
> export default function () {
>   console.log(exec.test.options.scenarios.default.stages[0].target); // 100
> }
> ```

Reading `exec.test.options` will show the actual option value used by your script, [per order of precedence](https://grafana.com/docs/k6/latest/using-k6/k6-options/how-to/#order-of-precedence):

> 1. First, k6 uses the option’s default value.
> 2. Next, k6 uses the options set in a configuration file via the --config flag.
> 3. Then, k6 uses the script value (if set).
> 4. After, k6 uses the environment variable (if set).
> 5. Finally, k6 takes the value from the CLI flag (if set).

If you want to check whether `--config` was used, you set a specific option only in this config file (e.g. a tag) and then check the consolidated options for its value.